# Can't change tabbar tintColor with a custom color

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

i'm trying to change the color of the tabbar with a custom color but seems that there is no way to do it ...

I have defined a category for the UIColor class in this way :

```
@implementation UIColor (UakariColor)

+(UIColor *) defaultUakariColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:237.0/255.0 green:28.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:0];
}
@end
```

I then i'm trying to set the color of the tabbar with my custom color in this way (in the custom tab bar controller) :

```
//Change the color of the tabbar
if([[self tabBar] respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)])
    [[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor defaultUakariColor]];
```

but it doesn't work (the tab bar is black ), if i instead set a standard color like redcolor :

```
[[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

It works, and set the color to red ...

Why with a custom color doesn't work ? Is it a BUG ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if u have `set` `alpha(opacity)` to `0` then it will be `like clear color` so it as per your `requirment` u `set` it to `1`. So do this:

```
@implementation UIColor (UakariColor)

+(UIColor *) defaultUakariColor {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:(237.0/255.0) green:(28.0/255.0) blue:(36.0/255.0) alpha:1];
}
@end
```